# Select all contenteditable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I'm trying to select all contenteditable div and change some of this functions:

```
$("div[contenteditable='true']").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).id);
   $(this).onblur="onDivBlur(this)" ;
   $(this).onmouseup="saveSelection()" ;
   $(this).onkeyup="saveSelection(this)" ;
   $(this).onfocus="restoreSelection(this)";

});
```

What am I doing wrong?
http://jsfiddle.net/mondayguy/oc2ooLto/
Can you also please provide me example of doing the same in pure js?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Which bit isn't working? are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors, even console.log do not printing id of editable div. I try to make jsfiddle now

Comment: Can you show an example of your html element too? and where your javascript is placed for initialisation?

Comment: Check it plz: http://jsfiddle.net/mondayguy/oc2ooLto/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $(this).attr('id') instead of $(this).id

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, this should work:-

```
$("div[contenteditable='true']").each(function(ind,elem) {
   //$(this).onblur = 
    alert($(elem).attr('id'));
   $(elem).onblur="onDivBlur(elem)" ;
   $(elem).onmouseup="saveSelection()" ;
   $(elem).onkeyup="saveSelection(elem)" ;
   $(elem).onfocus="restoreSelection(elem)";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
   $("div[contenteditable='true']").each(function() {

  alert($(this).attr('id'));
 $(this).onblur="onDivBlur(this)" ;
 $(this).onmouseup="saveSelection()" ;
 $(this).onkeyup="saveSelection(this)" ;
 $(this).onfocus="restoreSelection(this)";
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this as *onblur* and the other properties like *id* are handlers/properties attached to the element `this` but not the jQuery element `$(this)`:

```
$("div[contenteditable='true']").each(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   var self = this;
   $(this).blur(function(){
       onDivBlur(self);
   })
   .mouseup(saveSelection)
   .keyup(function(){
       saveSelection(self);
   })
   .focus(function(){
      restoreSelection(self);
   });
});
```

Note that I used jQuery's chaining to chain all of the handlers together without calling `$(this)` each time.  You can though add the `$(this)` if you want though.

EDIT:
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oc2ooLto/4/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("div").each(function() {
if($(this).attr("contentEditable") == "true"){
 console.log($(this).attr("id"));
 //REST OF YOUR OTHER CODE
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is the jQuery object referring to the matching element in each iteration of the "each" loop. Therefore, it doesn't have an 'id' property per-se. It is a jQuery object. Try this to access the id attribute of the element instead:

$(this).attr("id");